# How should I show share popup in Kony framework?

Tags: cross-platform, multiplatform, temenos-quantum

I'm creating the share function in a app with Kony Framework, but I don't see anything in Kony documents.

Anyone Can help me?

Thank you in advance for your time and consideration.

Comment: what do you mean by share function here? pls elaborate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is to write FFI for android and IOS separately and pass the needed data from JS to FFI.

For IOS , you can use URL schemes to determine what kind of share apps to open and for android depending on the intent action and data type  different share options can be shown

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to write one FFI for calling native share function. then you need to pass URL of application as an object for that method.